# Terminal Creating Alias Error

Tags: macos, terminal, alias

I wanted to create an alias in terminal (OSX) for this command:

```
cal -y | awk -v month="`date +%m`" -v day="`date +%e` " '{m=int((NR-3)/8)*3+1; for (i=0;i<3;i++) {t[i]=substr($0,1+i*22,20) " "; if (m+i==month) sub(day,"\033[0;31m&\033[0m",t[i]);} print t[0],t[1],t[2];}'
```

The command works perfectly fine when I just run it, but when I try to create an alias for it it gives me this error:

> Syntax Error near unexpected token `('

My code for creating the alias was:

```
alias caly='cal -y | awk -v month="`date +%m`" -v day="`date +%e` " '{m=int((NR-3)/8)*3+1; for (i=0;i<3;i++) {t[i]=substr($0,1+i*22,20) " "; if (m+i==month) sub(day,"\033[0;31m&\033[0m",t[i]);} print t[0],t[1],t[2];}''
```

I also tried to use escape sequences, as the error might be the fact that there are already single quotations in the command before I put the single quotations around the whole line. This is the second piece of code I tried (which gave me the same error):

```
alias caly='cal -y | awk -v month="`date +%m`" -v day="`date +%e` " \'{m=int((NR-3)/8)*3+1; for (i=0;i<3;i++) {t[i]=substr($0,1+i*22,20) " "; if (m+i==month) sub(day,"\033[0;31m&\033[0m",t[i]);} print t[0],t[1],t[2];}\''
```

Does anyone know how I can fix this error? I'm pretty new to terminal, so any advice is appreciated!

Comment: What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: So there's a "cal 2015" function in terminal that allows you to view a calendar of the whole year, but it doesn't highlight the current date. I found a command online that actually lets you do that, but since it's really long I wanted to create an alias for that command, and eventually save that alias in the bash profile file. But, the command for creating the alias wasn't working, so I was wondering if anyone knew what was wrong with it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The error is because the command string you're passing to `alias`, which is enclosed by single quotes, itself also contains single quotes.

I doubt there is a simple solution that still uses `alias`. I looks like you're pushing the expression passed to `alias` a bit too far. Consider putting your code in a shell script instead, and adding that script to a directory that is in your search path.